# SSIS Common rownumber for both outputs on a flatfile source

Tags: ssis

I have a small problem (I assume...)
I'm loading a flatfile (csv) and I want to add a rownumber to the dataflow. Using the RowNumber transforation works good for both output paths (source and error) individually. But what if you want to use the same rownumber in both paths to be able to track where (in the file) an error occured. I have scratch my head long enough now and I'm just throwing it out here since I'm pretty sure other people has tumbled across this one...

I have tried the script transformation which seems to work for a while but then it hangs the load.

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, dynamically generating the number with a script component for the dataflow is not a problem for you.

What I would recommend you is to adopt the following philosophy for stable etl processes coming from files:

1. Never cast anything in the connector, just import the fields as nvarchars of the maximum lenght they will achieve.
2. Cast and control each column to your specification.
3. If a row cannot be read, you will not know the index, but you will know that the file is malformed (extremely rare in my experience, for half transferred files), and it should be rejected anyway.

A quick screenshot of a part of a file loading process shows how the rejection (after assigning row_id) can work ([link to dataflow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB5hc.png)). To this you can add further countless checks (duplicates...) and even have a repository for the loaded files to check upon the rejects and whatever else you might want to control ([Link to control flow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5zRb.png)).

In some of my processes, I even use a flat file connector and just import each row as a bulk text and then split it in columns with an intermediate script component, allowing for  different versions of the columns in the files.

Anyway, sorry not to be more detailed (due to my status I can't add more links or any images), but I hope that you understand the concept.

Regards,

Francisco.